# Scroll View and Drawer Layout together

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview, drawerlayout

I cant scoll in my view. Below i have my code that i use.
Where is wrong i can define it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#BDC2C6">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/infotitlemain"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="22dp"
                        android:padding="22dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:background="#3585C8"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="330dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/main1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/infomain"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
                    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
                    android:layout_gravity="start">

                </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So i look at old questions but it looks like none of them doesn't work for me.
It seems i have something else wrong and i cant find it.

I work with android studio for my school app.

Comment: Try to have a single View inside the `ScrollView`

Comment: you mean one textview for example?

Comment: No.. You can do something like `<ScrollView><LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">     .......       </LinearLayout></ScrollView>` and in the ...... add your inner `LinearLayout` and the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`